# Difference when executing bash function in an alias

Tags: bash, alias

I have a function in my `.bash_profile` for printing text some pre-written text and copying it to the clipboard.

```
copyandprint () {
    s='\\033[1;32m' #strong
    n='\\033[0m'    #normal
    printf -- "printf -- '$1' | pbcopy;" #pbcopy copies to clipboard in macOS
    printf -- "echo -e copied '${s}$1${n}' to clipboard"
}
```

I use this to alias things I keep wanting to paste into other applications, like static IDs, or just silly things that are difficult to type quickly on a keyboard.

```
alias shrug=$( copyandprint '¯\_(ツ)_/¯')
```

[image: $ shrug #=> copied ¯_(ツ)_/¯ to clipboard]

But when I wanted to use it with text generated *at the time I use the alias*, I can't just call it in the alias definition; the alias needs to call it.

```
alias copydate=$( copyandprint "$(date)" )
```

[image: the time is from when the script was first executed, not when the alias was used]

The value is generated when the script is run, not when the alias is used.

Through pretty much sheer trial and error, I was able to make a modified version of the function that does what I wanted:

```
copyandprint_live () {
    s='\\033[1;32m' #strong
    n='\\033[0m'    #normal
    printf -- "$1" | pbcopy
    printf -- "echo -e copied ${s}$1${n} to clipboard"
}
alias copydate_live="\$( copyandprint_live \"\$(date)\" )"
```

[image: date generated at time alias is used]

The date is generated at the time the alias is used, rather than at the time the script is executed.

But when I use that function the way I used the other one, it fails:

```
alias shrug_2=$( copyandprint_live '¯\_(ツ)_/¯')
$ shrug_2
#=> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `ツ'
```

And I tried putting double quotes, but that didn't work

```
alias shrug_3=$( copyandprint_live '"¯\_(ツ)_/¯"')
$ shrug_3
#=> copied 033[1
#=> -bash: 32m¯\_(ツ)_/¯033[0m: No such file or directory
```

### My question is, what's going on here? Why do they need to be so different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dispensing with the aliases and using functions makes this a lot easier.

```
copyandprint () {
  printf '%s' "$1" | pbcopy
  printf 'copied \033[1;32m%s\033[0m to clipboard\n' "$1"
}

shrug () {
  copyandprint '¯\_(ツ)_/¯'
}

copydate () {
  copyandprint "$(date)"
}
```

Functions work alike any other command:

```
$ foo () { echo hi; }
$ foo
hi
```

Comment: If you are referring to my `shrug` function, there is zero benefit to defining the alias `shruggie` like that; you're just forking an extra shell to run something that can run in your current shell.

Comment: _The comment chepner is replying to above said:_ "You can also define an alias using that: `alias shruggie="$(shrug)"`"

Comment: But how do I use it in the terminal without defining it as an alias? The whole point of this was to have terminal aliases

Comment: A function is just a named command. You don't need an alias to refer to it; you just use it.

Comment: When I just type `shrug` in the terminal it prints `printf -- '¯\_(ツ)_/¯' | pbcopy;echo -e copied '¯\_(ツ)_/¯' to clipboard`. When I type `shruggie` it prints `copied ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ to clipboard` as desired

Comment: I redefined `copyandprint` to actually *do* the copying and printing, rather than generating the body of an alias.

Comment: I found using function in aliases can sometimes result in the command results in the function being treated as commands - e.g. ls -l will return an err.  Total:  command not found as it tried to execute the results of ls -l as a command WHEN in my .bashrc.  (but when just as a shell script it may work fine - this likely has something to do with other environment settings going on in . files

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the function when you define the aliases, not when you use them. You need to put the alias definition in single quotes to prevent `$(...)` from executing the command at that time.

```
alias shrug='$( copyandprint "¯\_(ツ)_/¯")'
```